# R: reshape2 long to wide replacing real values with integers between 1 and 3

Tags: r, reformat

Please bear with me since I'm a first time poster. I am attempting to take time series data from long format to wide format, but reshape2 (and reshape) are not outputting what I want. I am attempting to use cast or dcast to make my data into the following format

`id   State contract.type     Q1.2011   Q2.2011  ...  Q2.2014`

The source data is titled Med and is in the following format:

```
    > dput(head(Med))
structure(list(State = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AK", 
"AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", 
"IA", "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", "MI", 
"MN", "MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", 
"NY", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", 
"VA", "VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"), class = "factor"), Rebate.Category = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("FFS", "MCO"), class = "factor"), 
    Qtr.Yr = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Q1.2011", "Q2.2011", 
    "Q3.2011", "Q4.2011", "Q1.2012", "Q2.2012", "Q3.2012", "Q4.2012", 
    "Q1.2013", "Q2.2013", "Q3.2013", "Q4.2013", "Q1.2014", "Q2.2014", 
    "Q3.2014", "Q4.2014", "Q1.2015", "Q2.2015"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), NDC = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("30", 
    "64"), class = "factor"), Medicaid.Units = structure(c(290L, 
    306L, 320L, 228L, 162L, 320L), .Label = .Label = c("0.00", "4,010.00", 
    "4,076.00", "4,080.00", "4,084.00", "4,081.00", "4,089.00", 
    "4,091.00", "4,446.00", "4,440.00", "4,100.00", "4,104.00", 
    "4,151.00", "4,160.00", "4,161.00", "4,410.00", "4,414.00", 
    "4,418.00", "4,444.00", "4,451.00", "4,480.00", "4,488.00", 
    "4,440.00", "4,488.00", "4,500.00", "4,510.00", "4,558.00", 
    "4,560.00", "4,571.00", "4,600.00", "4,604.00", "4,610.00", 
    "4,678.00", "4,680.00", "4,740.00", "4,770.00", "4,800.00", 
    "4,850.00", "4,860.00", "4,910.00", "4,946.00", "4,960.00", 
    "4,971.00", "40,014.00", "40,440.00", "40,484.00", "40,166.00", 
    "40,180.00", "40,480.00", "40,500.00", "40,618.00", "40,740.00", 
    "40,770.00", "40,817.00", "404,460.00", "409,010.00", "44,406.00", 
    "44,440.00", "44,460.00", "44,510.00", "44,560.00", "44,580.00", 
    "44,700.00", "44,760.00", "44,841.00", "44,880.00", "44,940.00", 
    "44,948.00", "41,080.00", "41,400.00", "41,556.00", "41,600.00", 
    "41,780.00", "41,900.00", "41,960.00", "410.00", "414.00", 
    "44,010.00", "44,440.00", "44,751.00", "44,860.00", "44,880.00", 
    "44,040.00", "44,180.00", "44,880.00", "44,891.00", "45,000.00", 
    "45,484.00", "45,740.00", "45.50", "450.00", "451.00", "46,080.00", 
    "46,101.00", "46,160.00", "46,441.00", "46,560.00", "47,580.00", 
    "48,046.00", "48,060.00", "48,178.00", "48,846.00", "48,949.44", 
    "480.00", "49,440.00", "1,018.00", "1,046.00", "1,040.00", 
    "1,080.00", "1,400.00", "1,441.00", "1,460.00", "1,110.00", 
    "1,180.00", "1,446.00", "1,440.00", "1,491.00", "1,400.00", 
    "1,401.00", "1,460.00", "1,490.00", "1,491.00", "1,541.00", 
    "1,510.00", "1,511.00", "1,571.00", "1,640.00", "1,648.00", 
    "1,700.00", "1,741.00", "1,741.00", "1,760.00", "1,810.00", 
    "1,841.00", "1,846.00", "1,880.00", "1,896.00", "1,941.00", 
    "1,940.00", "1,941.00", "1,960.00", "1.00", "10,760.00", 
    "14,400.00", "14,600.00", "14,660.00", "144.11", "141,440.00", 
    "146.00", "11,680.00", "14,151.00", "14,510.00", "14,700.00", 
    "14,810.00", "14,891.00", "14.00", "140.00", "141.00", "168.68", 
    "17,460.00", "17,468.00", "170.00", "19,440.00", "4,000.00", 
    "4,004.00", "4,060.00", "4,071.00", "4,410.00", "4,450.00", 
    "4,480.00", "4,496.00", "4,188.00", "4,400.00", "4,441.00", 
    "4,410.00", "4,480.00", "4,600.00", "4,710.00", "4,711.00", 
    "4,840.00", "4,900.00", "4,941.00", "4,960.00", "4,964.00", 
    "40,741.00", "40,904.00", "40.00", "400.00", "404.00", "441.00", 
    "41,446.00", "44,000.00", "44,060.00", "44,746.00", "44,860.00", 
    "44,980.00", "45,400.00", "460.00", "47,160.00", "47,740.00", 
    "494.49", "4,010.00", "4,041.00", "4,080.00", "4,441.00", 
    "4,160.00", "4,410.00", "4,440.00", "4,610.00", "4,718.00", 
    "4,740.00", "4,768.00", "4,800.00", "4,910.00", "4,964.00", 
    "410.00", "415.44", "44,480.00", "44,740.00", "446.00", "444.00", 
    "45,418.00", "45,688.00", "46,418.00", "47,141.00", "47,180.00", 
    "48,410.00", "480.00", "484.00", "49,946.00", "5,040.00", 
    "5,400.00", "5,414.00", "5,460.00", "5,110.00", "5,180.00", 
    "5,440.00", "5,444.00", "5,441.00", "5,640.00", "5,760.00", 
    "5,794.00", "5,810.00", "5,946.00", "5,970.00", "50,810.00", 
    "51,480.00", "510.00", "540.00", "55,540.00", "56,110.00", 
    "57,661.00", "580.07", "588.91", "6,000.00", "6,060.00", 
    "6,410.00", "6,480.00", "6,140.00", "6,180.00", "6,400.00", 
    "6,480.00", "6,600.00", "6,646.00", "6,690.00", "6,710.00", 
    "6,900.00", "6.00", "60.00", "600.00", "64,044.00", "614.00", 
    "64,100.00", "660.00", "67,481.00", "690.00", "7,100.00", 
    "7,410.00", "7,451.00", "7,480.00", "7,500.00", "7,680.00", 
    "7,740.00", "7,760.00", "7,800.00", "7,860.00", "7,980.00", 
    "70,086.00", "70,680.00", "710.00", "74,800.00", "74,911.00", 
    "748.48", "751.00", "780.00", "784.00", "8,040.00", "8,460.00", 
    "8,510.00", "8,541.00", "8,584.00", "8,640.00", "8,740.00", 
    "8,880.00", "8,940.00", "840.00", "845.00", "9,000.00", "9,046.00", 
    "9,140.00", "9,400.00", "9,410.00", "9,480.00", "9,600.00", 
    "9,646.00", "9,660.00", "9,710.00", "90,140.00", "90.00", 
    "900.00", "905.00", "91,814.00", "960.00", "984.00", "996.77", 
    "0.50", "4,019.00", "4,044.00", "4,440.00", "4,480.00", "4,144.00", 
    "4,180.00", "4,400.00", "4,414.00", "4,468.00", "4,504.00", 
    "4,546.00", "4,551.00", "4,648.00", "4,710.00", "4,780.00", 
    "4,840.00", "4,980.00", "4.78", "40,080.00", "40,440.00", 
    "40,680.00", "40,851.00", "40,941.00", "40,914.00", "40,976.00", 
    "40,998.00", "40.00", "407,460.00", "44,044.00", "44,490.00", 
    "44,116.00", "44,176.00", "44,640.00", "44,810.00", "41,000.00", 
    "41,480.00", "41,140.00", "41,410.00", "41,480.00", "41,481.00", 
    "41,606.00", "41,841.00", "41,880.00", "41,908.00", "44,440.00", 
    "44,468.00", "44,680.00", "44,110.00", "44,446.00", "44,440.00", 
    "46,410.00", "46,680.00", "460.46", "465.00", "47,640.00", 
    "47,700.00", "47,810.00", "48,600.00", "48,900.00", "49,680.00", 
    "491.00", "495.00", "499.58", "1,048.00", "1,081.00", "1,410.00", 
    "1,456.00", "1,474.00", "1,476.00", "1,100.00", "1,114.00", 
    "1,184.00", "1,186.00", "1,456.00", "1,441.00", "1,484.00", 
    "1,580.00", "1,844.00", "1,941.00", "1.66", "10,150.00", 
    "10,181.00", "14,144.00", "11,440.00", "14,110.00", "14,404.00", 
    "144.09", "15,764.00", "154.45", "155.00", "16,580.00", "18,500.00", 
    "19,460.00", "19,510.00", "4,486.00", "4,108.00", "4,140.00", 
    "4,168.00", "4,408.00", "4,460.00", "4,464.00", "4,471.00", 
    "4,540.00", "4,660.00", "4,781.00", "40,061.00", "40,484.00", 
    "405.00", "44,447.00", "44,900.00", "441.00", "44,544.00", 
    "45,468.00", "454.87", "461.00", "47,080.00", "471.44", "484.00", 
    "496.78", "4,161.00", "4,480.00", "4,541.00", "4,560.00", 
    "4,571.00", "40,160.00", "40.00", "41,144.00", "414.00", 
    "418.00", "44,100.00", "44,400.00", "44,504.00", "46,500.00", 
    "46,860.00", "46,980.00", "47,445.00", "47,641.00", "47,880.00", 
    "470.00", "48,900.00", "484.00", "488.00", "49,740.00", "5,046.00", 
    "5,400.00", "5,484.00", "5,804.00", "5,880.00", "5,948.00", 
    "504.00", "51,065.00", "55,570.00", "55,680.00", "56,510.00", 
    "564.00", "57,468.00", "57,180.00", "584.00", "59,510.00", 
    "6,164.00", "6,460.00", "6,410.00", "6,660.00", "6,756.00", 
    "6,941.00", "6,948.00", "656.00", "680.00", "696.00", "7,080.00", 
    "7,441.00", "7,440.00", "7,146.00", "7,160.00", "7,456.00", 
    "7,560.00", "7,998.00", "744.00", "748.00", "8,400.00", "8,180.00", 
    "8,446.00", "8,446.00", "8,514.00", "8,580.00", "8,581.00", 
    "8,674.00", "8,700.00", "8,760.00", "8,810.00", "84,140.00", 
    "84,900.00", "840.00", "84.08", "87,410.00", "880.00", "884.00", 
    "89,700.00", "9,060.00", "9,064.00", "9,444.00", "9,664.00", 
    "9,780.00", "9,840.00", "9,900.00", "964.00", "0.89", "0.96", 
    "4,090.00", "4,451.00", "4,470.00", "4,106.00", "4,140.00", 
    "4,484.00", "4,418.00", "4,444.00", "4,444.00", "4,588.00", 
    "4,681.00", "4,718.00", "4,856.00", "4,891.00", "4,944.00", 
    "4.50", "40,068.00", "40,070.00", "40,488.00", "40,149.00", 
    "40,160.00", "40,410.00", "40,496.00", "40,596.00", "40,768.00", 
    "40,860.00", "40,916.00", "44,087.00", "44,400.00", "44,460.00", 
    "44,596.00", "44,646.00", "44,858.00", "44,881.00", "441.00", 
    "41,444.00", "41,840.00", "44,440.00", "44,100.00", "44,500.00", 
    "446.00", "44,496.00", "44,960.00", "444.00", "45,448.00", 
    "45,140.00", "45,456.00", "45,780.00", "45.00", "46,010.00", 
    "46,444.00", "46,941.00", "47,040.00", "47,466.00", "47,110.00", 
    "48,000.00", "48,049.00", "48,640.00", "48,645.00", "49,411.00", 
    "1,041.00", "1,041.00", "1,044.00", "1,094.00", "1,404.00", 
    "1,480.00", "1,171.00", "1,181.00", "1,188.00", "1,404.00", 
    "1,441.00", "1,546.00", "1,670.00", "1,818.00", "10.00", 
    "14,960.00", "11,010.00", "11,480.00", "11,488.00", "11,910.00", 
    "14,181.00", "14,490.00", "14,644.00", "15,100.00", "16,180.00", 
    "17,446.00", "18,946.00", "180.00", "19,460.00", "19,688.00", 
    "4,418.00", "4,481.00", "4,780.00", "4,946.00", "4.00", "41,040.00", 
    "41,400.00", "4,440.00", "4,100.00", "4,500.00", "4,580.00", 
    "4,680.00", "4,840.00", "4,946.00", "4,960.00", "4,980.00", 
    "4,981.00", "45,400.00", "476.00", "484.00", "486.00", "496.00", 
    "5,470.00", "5,510.00", "5,580.00", "5,688.00", "5,700.00", 
    "5,764.00", "5,940.00", "5,980.00", "54,491.00", "54,611.00", 
    "548.00", "551.00", "56.00", "6,078.00", "6,090.00", "6,446.00", 
    "6,464.00", "6,461.00", "6,474.60", "6,616.00", "610.00", 
    "611.00", "68,040.00", "7,010.00", "7,044.00", "7,058.00", 
    "7,084.00", "7,441.00", "7,440.00", "7,470.00", "7,646.00", 
    "7,676.00", "7,685.00", "7,696.58", "7,871.00", "714.00", 
    "718.00", "746.00", "75,540.00", "8,154.00", "8,761.00", 
    "8,866.00", "8.00", "9,040.00", "9,480.00", "9,414.47", "9,460.00", 
    "9,541.00", "9,540.00", "9,788.00", "9,810.00", "944.00", 
    "944.00", "4,064.00", "4,140.00", "4,450.00", "4,476.00", 
    "4,496.00", "4,591.00", "4,786.00", "4,941.00", "4,951.00", 
    "4.01", "40,010.00", "40,018.00", "40,196.00", "40,560.00", 
    "40,610.00", "40,764.00", "40,800.00", "40,980.00", "44,040.00", 
    "44,441.00", "44,591.00", "41,541.00", "44,441.00", "44,414.00", 
    "44,700.00", "44,950.00", "44,400.00", "44,704.00", "440.00", 
    "45,491.00", "45,450.00", "45,510.00", "45,788.00", "46,480.00", 
    "46,508.00", "46,571.00", "46,614.00", "46,860.00", "47,884.00", 
    "48,418.00", "49,500.00", "1,101.00", "1,451.00", "1,551.00", 
    "1,584.00", "1,676.00", "1,708.00", "1,984.00", "14,480.00", 
    "14,710.00", "14,400.00", "14,460.00", "15,500.00", "160.00", 
    "17,540.00", "17,847.00", "18,480.00", "4,068.00", "4,490.00", 
    "4,494.00", "4,496.00", "4,648.00", "4,704.00", "4,748.00", 
    "4,760.00", "4,804.00", "4,840.60", "4,867.76", "4,904.19", 
    "4,947.47", "41,880.00", "446.00", "46,691.00", "48,811.00", 
    "4,050.00", "4,409.81", "4,108.00", "4,500.45", "4,860.00", 
    "5,408.00", "5,441.45", "5,586.00", "5,944.00", "5,991.00", 
    "5.10", "6,061.00", "6,541.00", "6,771.00", "6,776.00", "6,780.00", 
    "641.00", "7,086.00", "7,444.00", "7,456.00", "7,541.00", 
    "7,610.00", "7,614.00", "7,644.00", "7,910.00", "7.76", "716.00", 
    "740.00", "8,188.00", "8,696.00", "8,740.00", "8,784.00", 
    "8,850.00", "860.00", "88.00", "896.00", "9,410.00", "9,450.00", 
    "9,141.00", "9,168.00", "9,404.00", "9,471.00", "9,661.00", 
    "9,964.00"), class = "factor"), id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("State", 
"Rebate.Category", "Qtr.Yr", "NDC", "Medicaid.Units", "id"), row.names = c("2185", 
"2184", "2182", "2180", "1503", "1501"), class = "data.frame")
```

id is just a rownumber. I subset by NDC into two subsets, Med1 and Med2. I then use the following code to cast. If I cast with id included on the left hand side of the equation, I get some of the right numbers. For instance, AK has 120 in Q4.2014,  but instead of putting the data in with one row for each state/rebate category pair, quarter by quarter, I have one good number per line and NAs for the rest of the time points. If I cast without id on the LHS, then I get an integer between 0 and 5 filled out for the entire sheet in every cell.

```
 TMed1<-dcast(Med1,id+Rebate.Category+State~Qtr.Yr,value.var="Medicaid.Units",drop=FALSE)
```

The output is

```
head(TMed1)
  id Rebate.Category State Q1.2011 Q2.2011 Q3.2011 Q4.2011 Q1.2012 Q2.2012
  1  1      FFS       AK    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
  2  1      FFS       AL    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
  3  1      FFS       AR    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
  4  1      FFS       AZ    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
  5  1      FFS       CA    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
  6  1      FFS       CO    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
Q3.2012 Q4.2012 Q1.2013 Q2.2013 Q3.2013 Q4.2013 Q1.2014 Q2.2014 Q3.2014
1    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
2    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
3    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
4    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
5    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
6    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
  Q4.2014 Q1.2015 Q2.2015
1  120.00    <NA>    <NA>
2    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
3    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
4    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
5    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
6    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

I also used the plyr id function to create a unique id for each combo of state and rebate combination as well, but I end up with the low integers again. Does anybody have any idea how to get the values of the medicaid column to go quarter by quarter for the unique id combos?

EDIT: Substituted original sample for dput sample recommended

Comment: You're more likely to get meaningful help if you (1) post a *small* sample dataset that illustrates your data and (2) show an example of the output you expect to get.

Comment: You should use the command `dput(head(Med))` to post your data in a format that can be used by others.

Comment: First thing I would do is make the 'factor' variables into 'character' vectors.

Comment: @topsig, thank you so much for the recommendation. I have edited that in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer! The answer is a combination of the recommendation from user1362215, BondedDust, and just tinkering. The answer is that fun.aggregate needed to be set to sum, but also the csv being exported from excel, and from which I was reading, lead to Medicaid.Units being read in as a factor when it should have been read in as an integer. I went to Excel and re-exported as a number field (without commas) instead, and it read in as integer and worked fine with user1362215's code. Formerly, his/her code was causing NAs to be generated whenever a number had a comma, but otherwise the cells were right and in the right place. Removing the commas and using fun.aggregate=sum solved the issue.

Thank you everybody!!! (I would upvote where appropriate if my account were old enough to have that privilege)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. Convert `Medicaid.Units` to numeric.  Currently it is a factor with 817 levels.
2. Set an aggregation function in the case of multiple entries per state/quarter/category/id.

   Med$Medicaid.Units = as.numeric(as.character(Med$Medicaid.Units))
       TMed1<-dcast(Med1,id+Rebate.Category+State~Qtr.Yr,value.var="Medicaid.Units",drop=FALSE,fun.aggregate = sum)

Comment: I have double checked your recommendation, but I have not been successful, and I have formerly tried coercion to numeric and integer as well, but it hasn't worked. I get lots of 0s instead of the data in the proper place, but at least the data isn't being coerced to random integers with sum. My id is assigned by Med <- transform(Med, id = as.numeric(interaction(NDC,Rebate.Category, 
State, drop=TRUE)))